# What is the escape character for "&" symbol? for vb.net

Tags: vb.net

from here:
CompanyCode=GB70 & HO&BucketLevel=1

I want it to read the & as code instead of separator.

currently it like this:
CompanyCode=GB70

expected result:
CompanyCode=GB70 & HO

Comment: Would a backslash `\ `  work?

Comment: Use double &. Like CompanyCode=GB70 && HO

Comment: Your question makes no sense. There is no escape character because there is no need of an escape character. The ampersand is a concatenation operator and that's it. If you want an ampersand character inside a literal `String` then put it inside a literal `String` the same as you would any other character.

Comment: The only place you'd need an escape character is in the `Text` of a `Label`, where an ampersand would be interpreted as an accelerator key. It certainly doesn't look like that applies to your situation, so no escape character needed.